# Move element 2 places up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to move an element two places up

I've tried lots of different options, but I can't get it right...
This is my latest code:

```
<div id="basket">
   <dl>
      <dt>Element 1</dt>
      <dd class="price">£32.00</dd>
      <dd class="qty"> 1x </dd>  //Need to move this element 2 levels up, right before dt

      <dt>Element 2</dt>
      <dd class="price">£6.00</dd>
      <dd class="qty"> 1x </dd>  //But this one as well
   </dl>            
</div>
```

```
$("#basket dd.qty").each(function() {
   var e = $(this);
   e.prevAll("dt").insertAfter(e);
});
```

Based in the code above, I want to display the .qty before its previous dt, so the result should be:

```
<dd class="qty"> 1x </dd>
<dt>Element 2</dt>
<dd class="price">£6.00</dd>
```

Comment: This would result in invalid markup, no? Ideally `<dd>` should have a `<dt>` (or `<dd>`) before it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#Basket .qty').each(function() {
  var sib = $(this).prev().prev()
  sib.before($(this))
});
```

```js
$('#Basket .qty').each(function() {
  var sib = $(this).prev().prev()
  sib.before($(this))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Basket">
  <dl>
    <dt>Element 1</dt>
    <dd class="price">£32.00</dd>
    <dd class="qty"> 1x </dd>

    <dt>Element 2</dt>
    <dd class="price">£6.00</dd>
    <dd class="qty"> 1x </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Please note that the ideal use is to have a `<dt>` before the `<dd>`

Comment: While this does what OP wants, it makes the first qty element an orphan and the second one the child of wrong dt.

Comment: @SalmanA Very true, honestly I miss read that part. I'll add a note to the answer about it.